# How to delete multiple files in MinIO in Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, minio

I have an DB entity, that is connected with many files storing in MinIO. How can I delete many files in one operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using minioClient you can try something like this:

```
List<DeleteObject> objects = new LinkedList<>();
 objects.add(new DeleteObject("my-objectname1"));
 objects.add(new DeleteObject("my-objectname2"));
 objects.add(new DeleteObject("my-objectname3"));
 Iterable<Result<DeleteError>> results =
     minioClient.removeObjects(
         RemoveObjectsArgs.builder().bucket("my-bucketname").objects(objects).build());
 for (Result<DeleteError> result : results) {
   DeleteError error = errorResult.get();
   System.out.println(
       "Error in deleting object " + error.objectName() + "; " + error.message());
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, I was trying to use RemoveObjectArgs class, instead of RemoveObject**s**Args